# How to fix "Facebook has detected MySite isn't using a secure connection to transfer information" in social-auth-app-django?

Tags: django, django-allauth, facebook-authentication

I have no idea why I'm getting this error, I'm all ears to hear from you.

> Facebook has detected MySite isn't using a secure connection to transfer information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you're not using https connection to send a secure data. That means your redirect url needs to be encrypted with ssl, otherwise facebook will show that message. So you need to get a certificate for that return url domain you provided facebook. Its also bad practice to send sensitive data over http as the data would not be encrypted and would be prone to interceptions like man-in-the-middle etc.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's the case. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Hey, if the answer solved your question, mark it as a solution. Thanks